# Need mysql update select query to be optimized

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `subcategory` and `listing_category`. `listin_category` table has different records which include `subcategory` and `category` as well. What i want is to find count for all the `subcategory` for specific `category` say category=3, in my `listing_Category` table and update it in `subcategory` table.
What i am trying to do it

```sql
UPDATE `subcategories` SET total_count = ( SELECT count( * )
FROM `listings_category`
WHERE category =3 and subcategory IN (subcategories.id)
WHERE category_id =3 and id=subcategories.id
```

I am having problem in making array `subcategories.id`. Any help will be appreciated. If any one suggest more optimized query that will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just say `in (select id from subcategories where whatever)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself :) I wonder why people vote negative for meaningful question.
Here is the solution.

```sql
update subcategories, 
       (
         SELECT subcategory,count(subcategory) as count 
           FROM `listings_category` 
          group by subcategory
       ) sb  
  SET subcategories.total_count = sb.count 
where subcategories.id = sb.subcategory
```

Comment: +1. Better use explicit ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of implicit comma one